# Looping through arrays mySQL insert

Tags: php, mysql

I need to loop through these arrays and put the values in their respective table which the table name would be medal+key i.e medal117

Here is the script:

```
<?php

//incude sql database connection
include_once('sql.php');
//include api key 
include_once('api.php');

$gameId = "448434948";
$gamertag = "Jam1efoster";

$GetGameDetails = "http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/game/details/".$apiKey."/".$gameId;

$output = file_get_contents($GetGameDetails);
$obj = json_decode($output);
//echo $output."<br/>";


foreach($obj->GameDetails->Players as $players) {
    if ($players->PlayerDetail->gamertag == $gamertag) {
        foreach($players->SpecificMedalCounts as $SpecificMedalCounts) {
            $medal = $SpecificMedalCounts;
            echo '<pre>'.print_r($medal,1).'</pre>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Currently it outputs:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Key] => 117
    [Value] => 1
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Key] => 2
    [Value] => 1
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Key] => 85
    [Value] => 8
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Key] => 101
    [Value] => 1
)
```

Comment: what's the problem though? you should just be using mysql_query to insert the data.

Comment: And what do you want to know exactly now? How to access `Key`?

Comment: @Felix Kling yes, how to access the key and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after anything more than this? Assuming you have already made the connection the the database.

```
mysql_query(sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO `medal%d` SET `value` = %d', $medal->Key, $medal->Value
));
```

Based on your comment to your questions, this is more about accessing the properties on a class.

From the docs, linked below:

> Within class methods the properties,
>   constants, and methods may be accessed
>   by using the form $this->property

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: Might as well run the `Value` value through `mysql_real_escape_string` while you're at it.

Comment: Except they are only being interpreted as integers in the sprintf (%d). Is there any reason to?

Comment: I don't like to make assumptions. Also, there's nothing to state that whilst the values (given the sample set) are all integers, they don't contain or require leading zeros.

Comment: I based my assumption off the combination of sample data and $SpecificMedalCounts as the variable name. It would fail if the code also counts fractions of medals.